# How to move/copy Windows 2003 Server scheduled task to Windows 2012 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

We are replacing an old 2003 server with 2012 server. We have 50+ scheduled task on the 2003 server. How can I export/copy the scheduled task from 2003 server and import those into 2012 server?

Comment: Probably belongs on ServerFault, and it's a dupe over there. http://serverfault.com/questions/43874/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-scheduled-task-from-windows-2003-job-to-windows-20 (Yes that question is for 2008, but the difference between 2008 and 2012 is minimal that if it works for 2008, it should work for 2012).

Answer (score 11):

**Step by Step easiest solution:**

1. Open Task Scheduler(TS) in Windows 2008 or 2012
2. Select top node on the left pane named "Task Scheduler(Local)"
3. Click on "ACTION" Menu on the top , and select "Connect to Another Computer..", Key in the IP address or the name of your 2003 server and click OK.
4. Click on the 2nd Node on the left pane named "Task Scheduler Library", you might get a message box with info "Copyconfig.job" no longer exists...just ignore it and click OK, you should see all your 2003 server scheduled jobs on the right pane.
5. Select the 2003 tasks one at a time , then right click and select export...export it to a known location.
6. Once you are done exporting all the 2003 tasks, close the Task Scheduler and reopen it.
7. Click on the ACTION menu, select Import and import from the exported location One Job at a time , make sure to user account under whom the jobs needs to be run in the new server.

Screen shots here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/467e5cab-2368-42de-ae78-d86b644a0e71/transfer-scheduled-tasks-to-server-2008?forum=winserverMigration

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the following when trying to connect to a 2003 server from 2008 (and up):
"Connecting as another user is only supported when connecting to a computer running Windows Vista™ or later."
how did it work for you, @AlanCarter ?